# Avoiding try catch when using local import from global glass and local class

Tags: python, package

I have the following global package structure:

```
- ML-global-package:
   - globalclass:
         - init.py
         - setup.py
         - globalclass:
                 - init.py
                 - data_uploader.py
                 - do_something_and_upload.py
```

Note that I'm packaging `globalclass` and using it in other packages

Within the global package, I'm importing into `do_something_and_upload.py` a `data_uploader` class from the `data_uploader.py` module

in order to check the `do_something_and_upload.py` from within the `globalclass` 
I'm importing it as

```
from data_uploader import data_uploader
```

but in the order it to work in other packages I need the following import to work:

`from globalclass.data_uploader import data_uploader`

So currently my `do_something_and_upload.py` looks like that:

```
try:
   from data_uploader import data_uploader
except:
   from globalclass.data_uploader import data_uploader
```

which obviously is a bad solution, how can I do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple approaches here:

1. Run your code from the same directory everytime - This will use the same PATH
2. Set manually the PYTHONPATH - bad practice
3. Use a single entrypoint for your application - create a module with global_class, with `python -m`

Comment: thanks! keep in mind that I will use both packages in a serverless environment, and both will be installed within a server which I don't have access to the File system